# Restar días a una fecha en INFORMIX

Tags: base-de-datos, sql, informix

Tengo la siguiente consulta INFORMIX, que saca una relación nombre y apellidos-nº de sucesos mientras se produzcan antes de hoy:

```
                select pa.nombre,pa.apellido1,pa.apellido2,tabla.suma
                from (select paci_key,count(paci_key) as suma  from sigur_episodiospacientes where date(fecha_alta) < (date(TODAY))  group by paci_key) tabla
                inner join  sigur_pacientes pa on pa.paci_key=tabla.paci_key
                where tabla.suma>1;
```

Necesitaba filtrar por las últimas 72 horas, entonces probé a cambiar el primer **`where`** por **`date(fecha_alta) > (date(TODAY) -3 DAYS)`** como pone en un manual de INFORMIX que he encontrado, pero la sentencia es errónea.

¿Alguna idea de como conseguir esa resta dentro del where?

Comment: cual es la columna que tiene el dato de la fecha?

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo fecha_alta.

Comment: In English, you should use `DATE(fecha_alta) > DATE(TODAY - 3)` (or `DATE(TODAY - 3 UNITS DAY)`).  In Spanish (thank you, Google Translate) — En inglés, debe usar `DATE (fecha_alta)> DATE (TODAY - 3)` (o `DATE(TODAY - 3 UNITS DAY)`). En español (gracias, Google Translate).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it worked, thanks!